# Save file without specifying Drive Location

Tags: vba

I would like to specify where my new Excel file is saved in terms of the folder (e.g. the folder name is Input Data). However, I do not want to specify the drive that it is contained in (e.g. C:\Input Data), how should I go about it?

I saw that other people typically would specify the full file path to where the folder is e.g. C:\Input Data. However, I would like to drop the C:\ portion.

The expected result would be where the output file is saved in the folder called "Input Data"

Comment: I'm just asking if it is possible, if it is not, you could just say no right? Why give pointless replies

Comment: Are you saying that Input Data must be the root folder?  I think it would be helpful if you could explain why you are trying to do this.  You could allow the user just to specify a drive, but it doesn't seem like good practice.  Bear in mind that using drive mapping I can change where _C:_ (or any other drive letter) is, ie I could have a mapped drive as _D:_ which is in a subfolder of C:

Comment: (And getting angry with people isn't going to help)

Comment: Hi Gareth, the reason for not specifying the drive, is so that the macro-enabled file can be run by another person on their computer, regardless of which drive they choose to save it to, as long as the file is in a folder called "input data". This is because this file will subsequently by read by another program where I have already indicated to read from a generic "input data" folder. I understand, just frustrated that people comment with things that do not help. After all, if I knew how to resolve it, I would not have posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to specify an unknown location you could use a system location.  Not only will this be consistent (for each user) but it should be a location where files can be saved.  Many systems have been set up not to allow folders to be created in the root of the C:\ drive.

```
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim pth As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")       'create a filesystemobject
    pth = fso.buildpath(Environ("userprofile"), "Input Data")  'get the path
    If Not fso.FolderExists(pth) Then fso.CreateFolder pth     'create the folder if required
    pth = fso.buildpath(pth, "My Workbook Name.xlsm")          'get the save path
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs pth                                    'save
    Set fso = Nothing
```

To see the other system folders see https://pureinfotech.com/list-environment-variables-windows-10/  You might prefer to use %TEMP%.

You will need to change the `Save` statement to suit